# espacios en repuesta archivo php

Tags: php, mysql

Amigos tengo el siguiente problema, al enviar una peticion mediante Ajax a un archivo php me responde perfectamente pero agrega espacios en blanco en la respuesta y no tiendo porque pueda ser, por favor su ayuda, lo agradeceria mucho.  lo que quiero es que me arroje solamente en este caso el numero que se genera sin esos campos, ya que en Ajax espero un numero.

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
require_once('../../conexion.php');
require_once('../../admin/sistema/php/crud.php');

$op = $_POST['operacion'];

switch ($op) {
    case 1: //Insertar o actualizar tanques y linea
        $linea = $_POST['linea'];
        $tanques = $_POST['tanques'];
        $tanquesOk = $_POST['tanquesOk'];
        $batch = $_POST['idBatch'];
        $modulo = $_POST['modulo'];

        /* revisar si existen un registro del modulo y batch para actualizar o insertar */

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM batch_tanques_chks  
                WHERE modulo = :modulo AND batch = :batch";
        $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $result = $query->execute([
            'modulo' => $modulo,
            'batch' => $batch,
        ]);
        $rows = $query->rowCount();


        /* Si existe un registro actualiza de lo contrario lo inserta */

        if ($rows > 0) {
            $sql = "UPDATE batch_tanques_chks SET linea =:linea, tanquesOk =:tanquesOk 
                    WHERE modulo = :modulo AND batch = :batch";
            $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $result = $query->execute([
                'linea' => $linea,
                'tanquesOk' => $tanquesOk,
                'modulo' => $modulo,
                'batch' => $batch,
            ]);
            if ($result)
                echo '1';
            else
                echo '0';
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO batch_tanques_chks (linea, tanques, tanquesOk, modulo, batch) 
                    VALUES(:linea, :tanques, :tanquesOk, :modulo, :batch)";
            $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
            $result = $query->execute([
                'linea' => $linea,
                'tanques' => $tanques,
                'tanquesOk' => $tanquesOk,
                'modulo' => $modulo,
                'batch' => $batch,
            ]);
            if ($result)
                echo '1';
            else
                echo '0';
        }

        break;
     }
 }
```

Respuesta

[image: Respuesta que me esta arrojando]

Comment: ¿En dónde están las etiquetas `<?php` y `?>`? ¿Puede que los saltos de línea estén antes y después de cada etiqueta?

Comment: Esos espacios pueden venir también de los archivos que incorporas en los dos `require_once` que tienes. Debes controlar siempre que no haya otras salidas por pantalla, incluyendo bloques HTML o cosas así, o que no haya caracteres BOM en tus archivos `.php`. Observo también que usas `rowCount()` para contar el total de filas. El Manual de PHP dice claramente que este método no es seguro para consultas de tipo `SELECT` ([ver lo que se dice en el **Ejemplo 2**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php)).